# Laravel 5.4 database session issue

Tags: php, database, session, laravel-5.4

I've spent hours to find this glitch, but I cannot. I would like to use database session instead of files. I did it and it has been worked for months, but now I changed something and didnt find what.
Laravel writes a session file instead of database.

I have checked everything:
The table is ok and all necessary settings too:

```
Session.php
  'driver' => 'app.database',
  'encrypt' => true,
  'connection' => 'mysql',
  'table' => 'sessions',
```

What else could be the problem? May I forgot to check somethig?

Comment: make sure you have a database and a table named sessions

Comment: I've already checked them. All were done.

Comment: check your .env file

Comment: Why `app.database` ? Isn't it just `database` ?

Comment: I have tried both app.database and pure database, but none of them has worked. I found this app. prefix suggestion somewhere.